# The number of distinct real roots of $x^7+20x^6-x^5-576=0$

Tags: calculus

> The number of distinct real roots of $x^7+20x^6-x^5-576=0$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ Let $f(x) = x^7+20x^6-x^5-576$

Then $f'(x) = 7x^6+120x^5-5x^4 = x^4(7x^2+120x-5)$

and $f''(x) = 42x^5+600x^4-20x^3$

could some help me to solve it , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your factorization of $f'$ is incorrect

Comment: Hint: 1) By Descartes rules of signs, what are the possible number of positive and negative real roots? 2)  $f(-2) = 608 > 0$

Comment: Check the signs of fxn at extreme values (±infinity) and at the zeroes of f'(x). I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$
p(x)=x^7+20x^6-x^5-576
$$
we have
$$
p'(x)=7x^6+120x^5-5x^4
$$
Then, using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we get

$$
\left(295791888x^5 +105722999425x^4 -8776210067485033\right) \left(x^7+20x^6-x^5-576\right) - \left(42255984x^6 +15224017015x^5 +41070490676x^4 -708294542210x^3 +12171528216940x^2 -1462904989461269x +12179289533760\right) \left(7x^6 +120x^5 -5x^4\right) =5055096998871379008
$$
which means that $(p(x),p'(x))=1$, and therefore, $p(x)$ has no repeated roots.

The [Sturm Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for $p(x)$ is
$$
x^7+20x^6-x^5-576\\
7x^6+120x^5-5x^4\\
\frac1{49}\left(2414x^5-100x^4+28224\right)\\
\frac1{1456849}\left(24745 x^4+119232288x+2048921280\right)\\
\frac1{24745}\left(5874015168 x^2+100697402880x-4195725120\right)\\
\frac1{10197943}\left(42255984x-14378897335\right)\\
\frac1{3099944763556}(-89499290024238519887119)
$$
which has $1$ sign change at $+\infty$, $2$ at $0$, and $4$ at $-\infty$. Sturm's Theorem says there is $1$ positive and $2$ negative real roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: The questioner wants the question to be solved by humans. If he wanted computers to do it he wouldn't have asked

Comment: @geekyme: I used a CAS to ensure the computations were correct, but I assure you, the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and Sturm's Theorem were used in detail. Now if you want this to be done *by hand*, then you'll have to wait for another answer.